# graphicsmagick losing exif data when converting tiff to jpeg

Tags: command-line, exif, graphicsmagick

I'm using gm convert on the command line to convert tiff to jpeg, but the tiffs exif data isn't in the jpegs. I can't see anything in the gm manual about this, would be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: See if you have any joy copying it across with `exiftool` maybe.

Comment: used XnView to do the conversion in the end, but exiftool would be easier to automate.